# Using tkinter as a start menu for another python program

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Hello I'm new to tkinter and coding. I am creating a project called a google bike. I found an instructable on it and I wanted it to look nicer by adding a start menu. It uses python and I am using tkinter to create a start page of some sort for it. I am trying to create a button where I would just press it in order to launch the program. This is the code I used to make the tkinter to make it look nice and sort of like a start menu.

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

def OpenServer():
      execfile("C:/users/Broadway Jewelry/Downloads/server/server2/server.py")

class Camacho(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(app):      
        tk.Tk.__init__(app)
        container = tk.Frame(app, width=800, height=500)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        app.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, Instructionspage, OptionsPage, DemoPage):
            frame = F(container, app)
            app.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        app.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(app, cont):
        frame = app.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(Frame):
    def __init__(app, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(app, parent, background='black', width=800, height=500)
        earth = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/Broadway Jewelry/Desktop/Bluestamp/earth.gif")
        BGlabel = tk.Label(app,image=earth)
        BGlabel.image = earth
        BGlabel.place(x=300,y=0,width=400,height=400)

        StartProgram = Button(app, text="Start Google Bike",
                          bd=10, command=OpenServer)
        StartProgram.place(x=100,y=75,width=200,height=44)

        Instructions = Button (app, text="Instructions", bd=10,
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Instructionspage))
        Instructions.place(x=100,y=150,width=200,height=44)


        Options = Button (app, text="Options/Setup", bd=10,
                      command=lambda: controller.show_frame(OptionsPage))
        Options.place(x=100,y=225,width=200,height=44)

        Quit = Button (app, text="Exit Program", command=quit, bd=10)
        Quit.place(x=100,y=300,width=200,height=44)

class Instructionspage(Frame):
    def __init__(app, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(app, parent, background='black', width=800, height=500)

        label = tk.Label(app, text="Instructions\n \nPedal=go forward\npress button=reverse\nbutton side to steer",
                     font=(200), background='black', fg='white')
        label.place(x=300,y=0,width=400,height=400)

        StartProgram = Button(app, text="Start Google Bike", bd=10, command=OpenServer)
        StartProgram.place(x=100,y=225,width=200,height=44)

        GoBack = Button (app, text="Go Back", bd=10,
                     command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        GoBack.place(x=100,y=300,width=200,height=44)

class OptionsPage (Frame):
    def __init__(app, parent, controller):
            Frame.__init__(app, parent, background='black', width=800, height=500)

            GoBack = Button (app, text="Go Back", width=50, bd=10,
                         command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
            GoBack.place(x=100,y=300,width=200,height=44)

            StartProgram = Button(app, text="Start Google Bike", bd=10, command=OpenServer)
            StartProgram.place(x=100,y=225,width=200,height=44)

            ShowDemo = Button (app, text="Show Demo Screen", bd=10,
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame(DemoPage))
            ShowDemo.place(x=100,y=150,width=200,height=44)

class DemoPage (Frame):
    def __init__(app, parent, controller):
            Frame.__init__(app, parent, background='black', width=800, height=500)
            earth = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/Broadway Jewelry/Desktop/Bluestamp/Google-Bike.gif")
            BGlabel = tk.Label(app,image=earth)
            BGlabel.image = earth
            BGlabel.place(x=300,y=0,width=400,height=400)

            GoBack = Button (app, text="Go Back", width=50, bd=10,
                     command=lambda: controller.show_frame(OptionsPage))
            GoBack.place(x=100,y=300,width=200,height=44)


app = Camacho()
app.mainloop()
```

I am thinking of finding some way to close the tkinter window and just have the python running the google bike. If anyone can help thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Just add a single line to `OpenServer` (which seems to be the function that runs the real program):

```
def OpenServer():
    execfile("C:/users/Broadway Jewelry/Downloads/server/server2/server.py")
    app.destroy()
```

I would also recommend that, within any given class, you refer to an instance of that class as the standard `self` rather than `app`. As it is, it's giving the impression that the `Camacho` object you instantiate at the end of the program is being passed around and referred to by its `app` name. However, that is not actually the case: in `Camacho`, `app` could refer to any `Camacho` object, even if you did something like `test = Camacho()`. Within `Camacho`, that `test` object would refer to itself as `app`. In the other classes, it's even more misleading, as the `Camacho` object named `app` is actually not `app` in there at all, but rather `controller`.

Confused? Even I find it messy - that's why it's better to use `self`, and avoid using the same apparent variable name in multiple scopes.